# Django | SyntaxError: invalid syntax al hacer ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

Admin.py devuelve el siguiente error al hacer manytomanyfield:

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo:** admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Actuacion
from .models import TipoActuacion
from fallo.models import Fallo

class ActuacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('resumen_actuacion', 'get_actuacion')

    def get_actuacion(self.object):
        return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in object.actuacion.all()])

class TipoActuacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )

admin.site.register(TipoActuacion,TipoActuacionAdmin)
```

**Archivo:** models.py

```
from django.db import models
from dispositivo.models import Dispositivo
from consumible.models import Consumible
from incidencia.models import Incidencia
from fallo.models import Fallo

class TipoActuacion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo actuación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de actuaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.
class Actuacion(models.Model):
    fecha_actuacion = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha actuación',null=True, blank=True)
    incidencia = models.ForeignKey(Incidencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    dispositivo_afectado = models.ForeignKey(Dispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    fallo = models.ForeignKey(Fallo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    actuacion = models.ManyToManyField(TipoActuacion)

    SOLUCIONADO_TYPE = (
        ('0','Sin solucionar'),
        ('1','Solucionado'),
        ('2','Parcialmente solucionado'),
        ('3','En observación'),
    )
    solucionado = models.CharField('Solucionado', max_length=50, choices=SOLUCIONADO_TYPE,null=True)
    resumen_actuacion = models.TextField('Resumen',null=True, blank=True)
    detalle_actuacion = models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True, blank=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Incidencia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Incidencias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resumen_actuacion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no puedes definir el `self` de esa forma en python,

```
def get_actuacion(self.object):
    return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in object.actuacion.all()])
```

Tu código debería quedar de la siguiente manera

```
def get_actuacion(self):    
    return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in self.object.actuacion.all()])
```

Revisa